# Не - слитно или раздельно: "неопределённо, но не насмешливо"

Tags: грамматика, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

> Выражение этого взора было очень *неопределённо*, но ***не** насмешливо*... ([Лермонтов](https://books.google.ru/books?id=aAFUVwju4csC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=sn1p8g_uLx&sig=zIrvUeO4cTsYqR1zcG_lGZWTuns&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F-C2VOP_L-LNygORjIG4Bg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), абзац со словами "Хорошенькая княжна...")

Союз **но** здесь имеет значение союза **и** -- это не противопоставление. *Насмешливо* здесь *краткое прилагательное*, а не наречие. Да даже если и наречие, значит *неопределённо* тоже наречие, но **не** с ним написано слитно.

Почему с первым словом **не** написано слитно, а со вторым раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Хорошенькая княжна обернулась и подарила оратора долгим любопытным взором. Выражение этого взора было очень неопределенно, но не насмешливо…"*

*ВЗОР* мог бы быть *нежным, ласковым, живым, весёлым, дерзким, насмешливым…*
 Трудно было разобрать, чему более соответствовал взор княжны. Ясно было только, что  был он явно *НЕ* ***насмешливый.***

Имеется отрицание, но отрицание только одного из понятий, могущих характеризовать взор княжны: *насмешливый.* ***"Не насмешливо"*** пишем раздельно.

Отрицания понятия ***неопределённый*** при этом нет, потому и нет необходимости писать это слово раздельно. Да и вряд ли возможно в русском языке  существование конструкции без ***не:***

*Выражение этого взора было очень определённо. **(?)***

Answer (score 2):

Выражение этого взора было (хотя) очень неопределённо, но (уж точно) не насмешливо.

В предложениях с союзом НО выбор написания НЕ делается по смыслу, как его понимает автор, а здесь отрицание, а не утверждение.

Да к тому же верно отмечено, что "ненасмешливо" вряд ли имеет реальный смысл. Попробуйте заменить синонимом. Серьезно? Задумчиво? Или еще как?

Answer (score 1):

> > Союз **но** здесь имеет значение союза **и**

Это почему? Вовсе нет. Но это к делу не относится.

Почему "не насмешливо" раздельно? Можно сказать так: потому что слова "ненасмешливо" не существует в языке. Не к каждому же прилагательному можно присобачить НЕ?

Ну, и отрицание здесь ясно чувствуется, а у "неопределённо", наоборот, не чувствуется. Особенно с "очень". Вспоминается лишь гоголевское "Очень не дрянь". ))